# The meaning of the REACH attribute on weapons

Tags: shadowrun-returns, shadowrun-hong-kong

I read the entire help menu and there is not a single mention of the REACH attribute for the sword or any other weapon that has REACH.

No information on Google either.

What's the meaning of that value?

Note: I don't know if the previous games had that attribute and if the purpose was the same, so I'm interested in the Shadowrun:Hong Kong version.

Comment: Usually, when something discusses "reach" as an attribute, it means the length of distance it can... *reach*.  In real life, take boxing for example.  A boxer usually has a stat known as reach, which is the distance they can extend their arm.  A higher reach may be advantageous against someone with a lower reach, for you may be able to hit them from a range that they otherwise cannot.

Comment: Thanks Timmy! My first impression is that a weapon with "10 reach" would mean that it could reach 10 squares away from the source... but since the weapon is a sword, I don't know how would that be possible besides "throwing the sword"... and that's not something that I saw in my first play-through... I saw people throwing shurikens and daggers... but never a sword :)

Comment: I seem to remember some melee swords in hong kong had an alternate effect that can be activated once per turn for a ranged attack.

Comment: Thanks! That must be it! Lack of description is a real problem in this game!

Comment: @lI you are correct... just brought the sword with me in a mission and the Lightning bolt option appeared in options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out why the sword has a REACH 10. The sword has a Lightning Bolt with Max Range 10.

It's a Damage 11 + armor penetration 2 + Stun 1 with cool down 2 and 1 AP.

[image]